# Could I provide a url to my git repository and ask someone to review my project?

Tags: support, scope, third-party

I recently had to write a program with unit tests as a coding assignment for a job. I didn't get the job and didn't get much feedback about my program. Would it be appropriate to explain what the program does and post instructions on how to clone it from github so that it could be reviewed and critiqued? Or is this too much to ask of others on the forum?
Thanks

Comment: Asking us to clone it from GitHub is not an option, the code has to be contained in the question itself. Does the code itself produce the correct output? If it's failing the constraints, it's not ready for review as per the [help/on-topic]. Please clarify.